# Tensorflow on a GPU slower than on a old CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-compute-engine

I just setup a GPU instance on Google Compute Engine and setup the GPU stuff as it is explained on the Tensorflow homepage.

While I think I completed the setup correctly (like installing drivers etc. to make the GPU available to the system) I think I a missing something out.

This is what happens if I start a small Tensforflow Python script that uses a simple MLP for testing purpose.

Here is the Python code (method of interest only):

```
def fit_model_with_nodes(self, nodes_count, X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, epochs=1000, batch_size=16):
    device_spec = DeviceSpec.from_string("/device:GPU:0")
    with tensorflow.device(device_spec.to_string()):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(nodes_count, input_dim=1, activation="relu")) #, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
        model.add(Dense(1))
        model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=["mean_squared_error"])
        history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), verbose=0)
        _, mse_train = model.evaluate(X_train,Y_train, verbose=0)
        _, mse_test = model.evaluate(X_test,Y_test, verbose=0)
        return mse_train, mse_test, history
```

And this is the corresponding output:

```
python Runme.py 

List of devices that can be used:
2020-05-29 11:25:29.741474: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-05-29 11:25:29.748052: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:102] CPU Frequency: 2200000000 Hz
2020-05-29 11:25:29.748221: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fac64000b20 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-05-29 11:25:29.748271: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-05-29 11:25:29.750619: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-05-29 11:25:29.977770: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-29 11:25:29.978410: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55901c0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-05-29 11:25:29.978508: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla P4, Compute Capability 6.1
2020-05-29 11:25:29.978755: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-29 11:25:29.979226: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla P4 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.1135GHz coreCount: 20 deviceMemorySize: 7.43GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.99GiB/s
2020-05-29 11:25:29.979607: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-05-29 11:25:29.981465: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.983258: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.983650: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.985508: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.986609: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.990324: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-05-29 11:25:29.990513: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-29 11:25:29.990972: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-29 11:25:29.991374: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-05-29 11:25:29.991453: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-05-29 11:25:29.992513: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-05-29 11:25:29.992576: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0 
2020-05-29 11:25:29.992614: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N 
2020-05-29 11:25:29.992768: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-29 11:25:29.993266: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-29 11:25:29.993711: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 7048 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P4, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 6.1)
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 8408828767664220178
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 18378745627352907163
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 8817804582458048379
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 7390920704
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 10457343079077620732
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: Tesla P4, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 6.1"
] 


Train Model with nodes_count =  768
1 /10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.995693: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-29 11:25:29.996097: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla P4 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.1135GHz coreCount: 20 deviceMemorySize: 7.43GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.99GiB/s
2020-05-29 11:25:29.996213: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-05-29 11:25:29.996254: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.996292: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.996330: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.996369: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.996407: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.996445: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-05-29 11:25:29.996522: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-29 11:25:29.996934: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-29 11:25:29.997307: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-05-29 11:25:29.997783: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-29 11:25:29.998240: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:00:04.0 name: Tesla P4 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.1135GHz coreCount: 20 deviceMemorySize: 7.43GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 178.99GiB/s
2020-05-29 11:25:29.998411: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-05-29 11:25:29.998488: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.998541: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.998589: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.998643: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.998692: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-05-29 11:25:29.998738: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-05-29 11:25:29.998856: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-29 11:25:29.999324: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-29 11:25:29.999720: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-05-29 11:25:29.999775: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-05-29 11:25:29.999811: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0 
2020-05-29 11:25:29.999845: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N 
2020-05-29 11:25:29.999949: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-29 11:25:30.000386: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-05-29 11:25:30.000811: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1247] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7048 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P4, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2020-05-29 11:25:31.037793: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
```

I do not have any particular experience in understanding the log output of Tensorflow but to me it looks as if TF has recognized everything correcly and is also using the GPU.

However, on my local machine (an old macbook pro from 2015 with an icore 5) is twice as fast as the GPU instance.

Is there something I have forgotten or is my setup incorrect?

Comment: This is not unexpected for such a low batch-size and such a small network. I'd suggest to retry with a larger batch-size (maybe 10k) and a larger network, you should definitely see an improvement then.

Comment: And if you don't see an improvement then, maybe there really is a deeper issue.

Comment: So, applying a GPU is only advisable if you are dealing with huge networks and huge amounts of data? This would be new to me...

Comment: Doesn't have to be huge, but not as small as your example. which has only one hidden layer and a scalar output. I have run benchmarks on this before, but they were for a previous employer. For example you can check out this blog post, which shows that for very small matrices, CPU is faster https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/hello-world-tensorflow-649b15aed18c#.ipfyuf5a2

Comment: The idea that GPUs are always faster is widespread, but false in general. The reason that it is widespread is that most benchmarks are concerned with performance on computer vision tasks, and therefore pretty much always use large CNNs, which do indeed benefit from GPUs a lot

Comment: Just to add to that: The reason for this is most likely the time required to copy to and from the GPU, which can be and often is a significant bottleneck.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for this information. Do you know wether this is a similar problem when dealing with TPUs?

Comment: I'd assume they have the same problem, but I've never used them before.

Comment: cool thanks for the feedback